# Is A/B testing possible using Mosaico?

Tags: civimail, mosaico, abtesting

When I go through the Create new A/B test workflow, it presents me with a traditional mailing interface, even though I have Mosaico installed.

I'm pretty sure that means A/B testing is not possible with Mosaico but wanted to check for confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

A/B testing for subjects is now possible (though not content or from details), as of Mosaico CiviCRM 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [2017 blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/mosaico-drag-and-drop-mailings-are-here): no, it's not implemented yet.

I think it should probably be opened as an [issue on github](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues).